# how to add image in left side of UITextField by using custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I add a view towards the left for more than one UITextField by subclassing custom class of UITextField. I know how to add a for a single field but not for multiple text fields.

Comment: Create separate leftview for separate UITextFields.

Comment: i don't want like that.help me how to create custom class of uitexfield and declare one method in that class & use in project where that method can needed if u know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @iPatel mentioned above we can achieve this with  @IBDesignable and @IBInspectable by subclassing UITextField.
I have created Extension by subclassing UITextField.[Here](https://github.com/udayeega/UKTextField) is the GitHub link.Please go through it.It has left view and right view.

UPDATE:

[image]
[image: Assign UKTextField]

In left Image Add your image.

Comment: tqs @Uday Eega but how to use that methods in my main class

Comment: No need to use them.Just give this class to all your TextFields.Then wait for some time to update attributes of this UKTextField class.After that you can see All Custom Options in Attribute Inspector.

Comment: please give me example. I have txtUsername textfield in my project give me example with this

Comment: 1.First take a UITextField.
2.Then select it.Then goto Identity Inspector.You can see UITextField in Gray Color.
3.Now drag UKTextField class in to your project.
4.Assign This UKTextField class in Identity Inspector where you have seen UITextField in gray color.
5.Wait for some time.Then goto attribute inspector.

Comment: See my Updated Answer

Comment: i did the whole thing I have small doubt how to add different image for different textfileds

Comment: Take as many TextFields as you want.Then Assign UKTextField class to each and every TextField.Then give images separately to each TextField.

Comment: tq so much uday eega

Comment: I have another doubt regarding alertview can i ask u

Comment: Sure you can ask me

Comment: I want to add alertviewcontroller in different classes for different situation but every time I am writing the total alertview declarion. I want to know how to declare alertview controller at particular place in my project & use that where it can needed. help me if know the answer

Comment: You can implement only showing alert like you want.But I don't know how to do actions with button click.

Comment: Add your alert initialization in singleton class. Call it whenever you want to show alert.

Answer (score 1):

I will not write code but my suggestion is you should go with **@IBDesignable** and **@IBInspectable** OR class **Extension**.

**1)**  Create your custom `UITextField` and customize as you want and add this TextField class to all of your TextField that you want to add left image.

Below is link for more ideas about it

- https://medium.com/anantha-krishnan-k-g/ibdesignable-and-ibinspectable-in-swift-3-702d7dd00ca

Or just search on google for **@IBDesignable** and **@IBInspectable** you will find nice tutorial for how to use in the project.

**2)** Extension :

You can create extension of any in-built class to modify it and create method that has code of left image addition. and call this method with object of your textfield class.

Below is link of extension

- [Create UITextField Extension in Swift with custom styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38850239/create-uitextfield-extension-in-swift-with-custom-styling)

Or just search on google.